# Tkinter listbox not displaying expected string

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is my question:

Im adding a string to a listbox created using two other strings.
This is all taking place in a loop.
Simplified code looks like this :

```
 a = "some string"
 b = "some other string"
 mystring = a.ljust(Some_Number) + " " + b
 print(mystring)
 myListbox.insert(myindex,mystring)
```

I would like to have something that looks like this in my listbox :

```
"dfasdfsdf             dfsd"
"sdfsdf                adfsdsfsaf"
"sd                    adfsdf"
```

Basically the second string always starting at the same 
index(Some_number + " ").
When I print it in the command prompt i get exactly what i want but in the Listbox the spacing is not the same and all over the place.
Any thoughts why this happens and how to fix it?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Is your listbox using a fixed width font?

Comment: I'm not sure, that is likely the problem, what fonts are fixed lenght and how can i set them?

Comment: You will need a fixed width font if you're trying to align your data in columns.

Comment: You can set the font with the `font` argument when creating the listbox, I don't know your platform but `Courier` is fixed width.

Answer (score 1):

```
mylistbox=tk.Listbox(myframe,font="TkFixedFont")
```

Hey guys the line of code above when initializing the listbox fixed my problem it was indeed a fixed width font problem, bit of a silly question... Thanks for all the help.